# Mongodb collection array limit

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I have several hundred JSON files with thousands of JSON array data on each files. These are the historical price data for things like CORN, OIL etcs

I am confused if I should create a MongoDB collection for each file(it can be as much as 1K files), for example CORN, OIL etcs or should I create one MongoDB Collection called ASSETS and then create an array called OIL, CORN etcs and import those JSON files?

I think and want to create one Collection called ASSETSand then add CORN, OIL data on array(So for example, I can fetch array like ~ASSETS.CORN...)  but I am not sure what is the limit of MongoDB collection's array. The array can grow to more than 100K.

I do not want to create 1K+ collections just to store historical data but I think keeping it on array would look clean.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not for us to answer, since we don't know what the data will be used for.

I will answer the question on how big a MongoDB Collection can be. 
In [this document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) you can find that a collection has no maximum number of documents, unless you set the threshold which, if set, is not bigger than 2^32 documents.

Don't be worried using a single collection, since even if you would cap it, 100k is not even near 2^32!

Databases themself are capped though! It is still 32TB of files, which is probably way more than you will fill with your data.

Comment: Thank You, it helps. I will add it to the document array of the collection.